# how to use two .bib files?

Tags: bibtex

I have made two .bib files for storing different sources I have.  However, when I use the command

```
\bibliography{/Users/prinelo/Desktop/Database/mylib,mylib2}
```

only the first file is found. What can I do for this?

Comment: is mylib2 in the same directory as your main document?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of simplifying the title and deleting the entire first sentence, as the posting is wholly unrelated to `natbib`.

Comment: yes. @DavidCarlisle they are in the same directory.

Comment: what happens if you put it in the same directory as `mylib` and use `\bibliography{/Users/prinelo/Desktop/Database/mylib,/Users/prinelo/Desktop/Database/mylib2}`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. But I didn't find any file named texmf in my computer. I use TexStudio with MacTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two bib files are in the same place then

```
\bibliography{/Users/prinelo/Desktop/Database/mylib,/Users/p‌​rinelo/Desktop/Datab‌​ase/mylib2}
```

should work, it is also possible to put them in a standard place in the search path, either the directory with the main docuemnt, or a directory such as `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/local` then the following would work, making your document more portable.

```
\bibliography{mylib,mylib2}
```